# Multi WAN ipv4 forward Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, routing, wide-area-network, iproute2

I want to setup a dual ethernet ubuntu machine as Multi-WAN load-balance router with ipv4 forwarding and NAT for my internal network.

I searched for some days now, but only found some tutorials how to setup load balancing **or** ipv4 frowarding. But none of them combines the two.

My setup is:

```
eth1: #external network
Network: 192.168.69.0/24
IP: 192.168.69.70
Gateway1: 192.168.69.1
Gateway2: 192.168.69.3
Gateway3: 192.168.69.4

eth0: # internal network
Network: 192.168.20.0/24
IP: 192.168.20.20
```

So the Computer should connect to the three gateways, setup load-balance and then use this table to forward with NAT to the internal Network, so I can use it as Gateway for my internal network.

I've no plan how to setup such a complex routing.

Can someone help me please?

Thanks in advance,
Michael

Comment: Have you read through chapter 4 of this yet?  http://lartc.org/howto/  What exactly do you mean by ipv4 forwarding?  Your 3 gateway addresses all have an private IP address, are they not doing NAT already?

Comment: This chapter only describes how to setup split access and load balancing. But I dont know how to forward it..

Comment: With ipv4 forwarding I mean that I can use the Ubuntu machine as gateway for my internal network. Yes they are doing NAT already but I want that the internal net can reach the external network but the external network can not reach the internal one..